# Nokogiri parsing missing element create issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

I am having Plain html doc NO CSS . In which some of the content i need to pass to excel sheet. I tried with Nokogiri it works on Css basis.

Do anybody tried this thing.

```
<html>
 <head></head>
  <body>
    ***NOTE***
   <br>
      Items 
   <br>
   <br>
      Invoice Number : [78945824] PO Number : [4587958]
   <br>
       Track It : <a href="abc.com"> 12345</a>
   <br>
   <br>
      Items 
   <br>
   <br>
      Invoice Number : [79546828] PO Number : [4567892]
   <br>

   <br>
   <br>
      Items 
   <br>
   <br>
      Invoice Number : [78976824] PO Number : [897569]
   <br>
      Track It : <a href="abc.com"> 12345</a>
   <br>
   </body>
   </html>
```

I am able to retrieve the PO Number & Tracking no

```
  require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'   
require 'open-uri'

PAGE_URL = "a.html"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(PAGE_URL))
    data = page.css("body").text

    po_numbers = data.scan(/Invoice Number : \[\d+\] PO Number : \[(\d+)\]/).flatten
    tracking_numbers = page.css("a").text.split

    [["PO Number", "Tracking Number"]].concat(po_numbers.zip(tracking_numbers))
 puts po_numbers
 puts tracking_numbers


=> po_numbers = ["4587958", "4567892", "4587958"]
=> tracking_numbers = ["12543", "12356"]
```

When we zip those together, we get:

```
=> po_numbers.zip(tracking_numbers)
=> [["4587958", "12543"], ["4567892", "12356"], ["4587958", "nil"]]

What we want is:

=> [["4587958", "12543"], ["4567892", "nil"], ["4587958", "12356"] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
data = page.css("body").text
data = data.gsub(" ","").split(/\n/)
po=[]
track=[]
data.each do |i|
  if i.include? "PONumber"
    po << i.split("PONumber:").last.scan(/\d+/)[0]
  end
  if i.include? "TrackIt"
    track << i.split("TrackIt:").last
  end
end
po.zip(track)
```

Comment: It gives me only on element which not having the Track IT no

Comment: I ran this same code and gives the result as u want.

Comment: I am getting only one value [["4567892", nil]] I need full hash

Comment: my output `[["4587958", "12543"], ["4567892", nil], ["897569", "12543"]]`

Comment: you are dealing with Track It : <a href="abc.com"> 12345</a> because i m not getting same hash value :(

Comment: can you check the answer i have modified it

Comment: Thanks sagar can i have your email address so i can drop you my actual html file..because your code gives me only one value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79513/discussion-between-swagh-and-sagar-patil).

Answer (score 1):

If you can use regex to scan for all invoice number (**po_numbers**), you can do the same with tracking number (**tracking_numbers**):

```
tracking_numbers = data.scan(/Tracking no : (\d*)/).flatten
```

The returned array includes **nil**, therefore, you can walk through both array for po number and tracking number

```
po_numbers.each_with_index do |elm, index| 
  p "PO Number: #{elm}, Tracking Number: #{tracking_numbers[index]}"
end
```

**Update**

This regex match the updated HTML

```
/Track It :\s*(?:<a href=".*">\s*(\d+)\s*<\/a>|$)/
```

It matches both empty track number and one with *a* link.

Comment: In Tracking no i am having value text with href tag. how to parse that by nokogiri

Comment: Thanks could you just let me know how you build the regex.

Comment: You have to learn Ruby regex (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html) first. Rubular (http://rubular.com/) is an online-tool to quickly test the regex.

Comment: Thanks Yen. If i have the updated HTml how to deal with this because i am not having any tags

Comment: Regex does not depend on tags. So if your HTML is updated, you need to adjust your original regex accordingly. If you use only regex for po and tracking number, you actually do not need nokogiri anymore.